# Flutter setState not updating a particular widget

Tags: flutter, setstate

I am using [multi_select_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/multi_select_flutter) to show multi chips in my flutter project. However, am trying to add more items to the chip with data loaded from my api while the user is searching but it doesn't update the state of the multi chip widget. Here is my full code.

Even when I hot reload, it does not update itself. The only way I can manually enforce a refresh update is to re-ad the widget and reload consecutively. Any information as to why this strange behavior happens?

```
class MultiChoiceComponent extends StatefulWidget {
  const MultiChoiceComponent({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MultiChoiceComponentState createState() => _MultiChoiceComponentState();
}

class _MultiChoiceComponentState extends State<MultiChoiceComponent> {
  ApiMethods apiMethods;

  TextEditingController searchController = TextEditingController();
  List<MultiSelectItem<dynamic>> labels = [];
  final TextEditingController textEditingController = TextEditingController();
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    apiMethods = new ApiMethods(context: context);
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      children: [
        Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
          child: Text(
            'Search and select as many symptoms been experienced, it helps with a more accurate diagnosis',
            textAlign: TextAlign.start,
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 14,
              height: 1.8,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
              fontFamily: 'Euclid',
              color: AppColors.grey1,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 20,
        ),
        Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16,),
          // height: maxLines * 50.0,
          child: TextField(
            controller: textEditingController,
            cursorColor: Colors.black26,
            onChanged: (val){
              if(val!=""){
                searchSymptoms(val);
              }
            },
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                filled: true,
                hintStyle: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 14,
                  height: 1.6,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                  fontFamily: 'Euclid',
                  color: AppColors.grey1,
                ),
                hintText: "Search for a symptom/illness",
                fillColor: Colors.white,
                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0, vertical: 14),
                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: AppColors.textColor.withOpacity(0.5)),
                ),
                focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: AppColors.textColor.withOpacity(0.5)),
                ),
                enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: AppColors.textColor.withOpacity(0.5)),
                )),
          ),
        ),
        MultiSelectChipField(
          scroll: false,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: Border.all(color: Colors.transparent, width: 1.8),
          ),
          showHeader: false,
          selectedTextStyle: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 12.5,
            height: 1.8,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
            fontFamily: 'Euclid',
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
          chipShape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
              Radius.circular(12),
            ),
          ),
          selectedChipColor: AppColors.customGreen,
          chipColor: Colors.white,
          textStyle: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 12.5,
            height: 1.8,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
            fontFamily: 'Euclid',
            color: AppColors.textColor,
          ),
          items: labels,
          onTap: (value) {
            ///add symptoms to list
            print(value);
            selectedSymptoms = value as List<Conditions>;
          },
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
  Future<void> searchSymptoms(String searchQuery) async {
    List<dynamic> _data =  await apiMethods.searchConditions(symptomCheckerAge, searchQuery);
    conditions = Conditions.fromJsonList(_data);
    labels = conditions.map((e) => MultiSelectItem(e, e.label)).toList();
    setState(() {});
  }
}
```

Comment: where is the execution\trigger of `searchSymptoms()` ?

Comment: it happens inside a text field as a search trigger. I didn't add that to the code though

Comment: Can you include `labels`

Comment: please review my full code @Hardik

Comment: @Hardik I tested with labels and it works perfectly. It doesn't seem to work with the chip widget

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this given Chip Widget with custom data and it is working properly.. Meaning the items that I am adding on pressed are being added to the new list. Take a look and try out the few changes and see if that works for you

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
    static List<Animal> _animals = [
    Animal(id: 1, name: "Lion"),
    Animal(id: 2, name: "Flamingo"),
    Animal(id: 3, name: "Hippo"),
    Animal(id: 4, name: "Horse"),
    Animal(id: 5, name: "Tiger"),
    Animal(id: 6, name: "Penguin"),
    Animal(id: 7, name: "Spider"),
    Animal(id: 8, name: "Snake"),
    Animal(id: 9, name: "Bear"),
    Animal(id: 10, name: "Beaver"),
    Animal(id: 11, name: "Cat"),
    Animal(id: 12, name: "Fish"),
    Animal(id: 13, name: "Rabbit"),
    ];
    dynamic _items = _animals
      .map((animal) => MultiSelectItem<Animal>(animal, animal.name))
      .toList();
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text('Hello'),
      ),
      body: ListView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        children: [
          Container(
            child: MultiSelectChipField(
              scroll: false,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border.all(color: Colors.transparent, width: 1.8),
              ),
              showHeader: false,
              selectedTextStyle: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 12.5,
                height: 1.8,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                color: Colors.blue,
              ),
              chipShape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                  Radius.circular(12),
                ),
              ),
              selectedChipColor: Colors.green,
              chipColor: Colors.yellow,
              textStyle: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 12.5,
                height: 1.8,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
              items: _items,
              onTap: (value) {
                ///add symptoms to list
                print(value);
              },
            ),
          ),
          ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                _items.add(MultiSelectItem<Animal>(
                    Animal(id: 27, name: 'name'), 'new'));
                setState(() {});
              },
              child: Text('Add'))
        ],
      ),
      );
     }
    }

     class Animal {
      final int id;
      final String name;

    Animal({
    required this.id,
    required this.name,
    });
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Future<void> searchSymptoms(String searchQuery) async {
    List<dynamic> _data =  await apiMethods.searchConditions(symptomCheckerAge, searchQuery);
      conditions = Conditions.fromJsonList(_data);
      labels = conditions.map((e) => MultiSelectItem(e, e.label)).toList();
    setState(() {});
}
```

Comment: it doesn't work bro even by hot reload, I wonder if its from the package

Comment: please review my full code

Comment: I believe the "fix" for this is to update the key for the widget. See answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/72080820/8666381

Answer (score 0):

I was also struggling with hot reload of the `MultiSelectChipField` and the solution was to update the globalkey during reload.

Pseudo code:

```
  late var _multiSelectKey;
  late List<MultiSelectItem<SomeClass?>>? _items;

  @override
  void initState() {
       _items = null;
  }
    
  void reloadChip()
  {
    _multiSelectKey = GlobalKey<FormFieldState>();
    _items = getItemsFromSomeWhere();
  }
```

In scaffold the chip has these params

```
MultiSelectChipField<SomeClass?>(
                  initialValue: getSelected(),
                  key: _multiSelectKey,
                  title: const Text("Title"),
                  items: _items!,
                  onTap: (items) async { },
                  },
                ),
```

When function `reloadChip()` is called and a `setState(() {});` is triggered the `MultiSelectChipField` will update.